# Adding javascript function to jMeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am trying to get a javascript function work with jMeter test plan.
It is used to decode a string.

```
function decode(str) {
    var strtodecrypt = str.split("-");
    var msglength = strtodecrypt.length;
    decrypted_message = "";
    for (var position = 0; position < msglength; position++) {
        ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt = strtodecrypt[position];
        ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt = ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt / 2;
        ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt = ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt - 5;
        decrypted_byte = String.fromCharCode(ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt);
        decrypted_message += decrypted_byte;
    }
    return decrypted_message;
}
```

I have tried to use BSF Post processor, but don't know what is the exact syntax i need to use. I want to use this function to post a jMeter variable as a parameter in one of the HTTP request.

**Edit:**  I am currently using following script in the BSF post processor. `userResponse` does not show in debub sampler. Do i need to add any reference to use `String.fromCharCode(ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt)`?

```
var str="142";
var strtodecrypt = str.split("-");
var msglength = strtodecrypt.length;
decrypted_message = "";

for (var position = 0; position < msglength; position++) {
    ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt = strtodecrypt[position];
    ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt = ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt / 2;
    ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt = ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt - 5;
    decrypted_byte = String.fromCharCode(ascii_num_byte_to_decrypt);
    decrypted_message += decrypted_byte;
}

vars.put("userResponse",decrypted_message);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use as well [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with script language set to javascript (`Language: JavaScript`).
It will process your script (2nd version), variable set and available in debug Sampler results.

Answer (score 0):

You should WebDriver plugin for that. It can be configured as IE/Firefox/Chrome or even Selenium.

The documentation [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

This is how you configure [IE web driver](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InternetExplorerConfig/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=InternetExplorerConfig)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this years later:

#### Calling javascript function is possible from a BSF PostProcessor.

You need to define your function **higher up** in the file than where it is used.

This means this works:

```
function decode(str) {
    (...... do stuff......)
    return something;
}

var bar = decode("foo");
vars.put("someVariableName", bar);
```

However this doesn't work:

```
var bar = decode("foo"); // <--- Compile error, undefined function 'decode'
vars.put("someVariableName", bar);

function decode(str) {
    (...... do stuff......)
    return something;
}
```