# Working with HMAC authentication in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jmeter

I am doing performance testing of Web Services which involves HMAC authentication. Details are:

1. A java script has been developed which will create a signature, MD5
   code and nonce number before a request is sent from the API
2. This information generated above will be passed on to variables
       defined in the script which will authenticate before making a
       request.
3. Once authentication is successful the request will be sent and
       valid response will be obtained from DB.

script needs to be put in a beanshell preprocessor of Jmeter:
[image]

This script will be generating values for the header manager which in turn will do authentication process.
[image]

The problem is the language in which the script has been written ( JS ) is not compatible with Jmeter i.e `jmeter` cannot use the script created because it does not understands the language of the script. I came to know that the script has to be modified probably using jquery so that the jmeter beanshell can interpret it and generate values for
Date
MD-5
Signature

How can I change it to jQuery or is there any possibility to get similar JQuery code, as I do not have much java script coding background.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSR223 Sampler with script language set to javascript (Language: JavaScript).

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853893/5159450